# How to edit the subtitle/tagline in mobile Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

In mobile version of Wikipedia, some articles have a subtitle AKA tagline. For example, in [the article about Executive Order 13769](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13769) it says "United States executive order about foreigners entering the U.S."

[image: Wikipedia screenshot]

The problem is, I can't find how to edit it. The text it contains cannot be found in the page source.

Comment: I wonder why it is not visible on desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the description field from [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page), a sister site of Wikipedia that stores information about articles in structured data that can be used easily by machines. That article's Wikidata item is [Q28543928](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q28543928). The link for any Wikipedia article can be found by clicking "Wikidata item" on the left-side toolbar in desktop view, but I don't see the link on the mobile version.